# How to communicate between joomla components?

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla2.5

In my website a registered user navigates through various components, I am thinking of using session variable for all communications between components instead of a POST /GET. Is this a right thing to do?

I have several custom joomla 2.5 components written by me. Things like login welcome page, application1 and so on. Now the welcome page has buttons to these applications and instead of using a post/get I am thinking of using session variables. I am new to web technologies and I want to know pros and cons of this approach.

Comment: Please add a bit more information to you question. What Joomla version? Which components? Why?

Comment: @lodder thank you for your reply, I have added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use superglobals like `$_SESSION` when you're using a CMS like Joomla.  Instead, use:

```
JRequest::setVar("varName");
```

and

```
JRequest::getVar("varName");
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to learn that, I did not know that. Another sub question, are these variable reset when user logs in or out or should that be done by code.